# Binary data to string conversion failing

Tags: javascript, html

I'm able to unpack binary data to a string from a websocket and successfully able to display the text string (using console.log) but unable to assign the output to an document using the the correct ID...

```
var a = String.fromCharCode.apply( null, new Uint8Array( msg.data ) );
console.log( "output: " + a );

// fails here :(
document.getElementById("session0").textContext = a + "\n";

// if the msg data is a text field this is fine
document.getElementById("session0").textContext = msg.data + "\n";
```

Any help appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to type textContent instead of textContext there?

Comment: Thanks, what a....! Thank you... Is there anyway of assigning part of the buffer to an element?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. I suggest you compose a new question for that , with a jsfiddle or jsbin example.

Answer (score 0):

'textContent' may not be the suitable property to set, maybe you should set 'value' or 'innerHtml' instead, depending on the type of element "session0" is.

Comment: If I wanted to assign part of the buffer i.e the first 10 bytes is that possible?

Comment: I thought the problem was with the output. You can get part of the array containing the charachters with 'slice'.
var chars = new Uint8Array( msg.data );
var beginning = chars.slice(0,10);

Comment: Sorry it was but Phil H pointed out that my syntax was incorrect :(